# Illustrator: remove curves from multiple points

Tags: adobe-illustrator, anchor-point

I have some shapes i am working with in illustrator CS5 and I want to remove the curves from some of the points.

Normally i would use the convert anchor point tool and single click each point, however i have a lot of points i need to do this to.  Is there a menu item that will apply this function to multiple points at one time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could select the points you want with the Direct Select Tool and next the the word Convert select the icon that says "Convert selected anchor points to corners".

Depending on where the anchor points are, you can left click and drag to select multiple anchor points at once.

[image: anchor selections]

Comment: Is this available in CS5?  where are the convert buttons located?

Comment: @Harry Yes, when you have any anchor point selected, it is at the top left under the menu options. it is the same options as when you have the pen tool in use. The main difference in my method is using the direct select tool to select multiple anchor points at once.

Comment: Thanks, this worked, but i had to do a bit extra.  if i selected all of the points in a group of shapes i didn't get this menu, i had to de-select one point in order for it to show up.  I also had to click the round one first then the corner one in order for it to remove the handles.

Answer (score 3):

In CS6 (and maybe in earlier versions), select the path you want to remove the curves from, click Object > Path > simplify and tick the "straight lines" - box. this should do it.

I translated the terms from the german version, so they might not be completely identical.

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know how to accomplish this is with a plug-in for Illustrator called "Vector Scribe" by Astute Graphics. Within "Vector Scribe" is a tool called "Path Scribe" and this allows you to retract the handles of all points you have selected at one time. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

In Illustrator 2019 select the path you want to change and choose Object/Path/Simplify from the menu bar. The check box for straight lines will be in that dialogue box.